# Named pipes error when connecting to remote Express Edition server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition through a Remote computer.
I am getting this error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

On running `SELECT CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')) instancenameting`

I get `NULL` as the instance name. I have started SQL Browser service, checked TCP/IP are enabled.

What else can be done?

Comment: If you can login into it as `localhost` what do you get for `Select @@Servername`?

Comment: it is showing a different name something like IP-0A6E3175

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you are connecting to the server: are you using SSMS, another application or your own code? If it's your code, what does the connection string look like? The error mentions named pipes, not TCP/IP, so something may be misconfigured. There is a nice overview of troubleshooting this error [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx).

Comment: Then `IP-0A6E3175` is the name of your SQL Instance and that is what you want to use as the server in your connection string.

Comment: I am connecting using C#, through my own code. connection string looks like : Data Source=<<server name>>;Initial Catalog=<<database name>>;Persist Security Info = True;User ID=<<username>>;password=<<password>>

Comment: You want to use the SQL Server Instance as the Data Source, not the name of the server that the SQL Server Instance resides on.

Comment: Replaced the connection string with Data Source = IP-0A6E3175 .. Still not able to connect

Comment: And did you try the IP address? Did you ensure that named pipes and TCP/IP are enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager? Did you check if you have a firewall issue (e.g. see if you can telnet to port 1433)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Data Source=IP-0A6E3175;Network=DBMSSOCN;...
```

Or

```
Data Source=<<ip address>>;Network=DBMSSOCN;...
```

You'll also need to make sure that TCP/IP is enabled on the host using SQL Server Configuration Manager, that you aren't blocked by a firewall, etc.

And just for kicks, also please try:

```
Data Source=<<ip address>>\SQLEXPRESS;Network=DBMSSOCN;...
```

Comment: I tried changing the connection string as mentioned by you... but no effect. TCP/IP and named pipes are already enabled, and I tried with firewall off

Comment: @user2129794 but you get a different error message now, right? Why do you have `Persist Security Info...`?

Comment: @user2129794 there cannot be "no effect"  The error message should change to no longer mention named pipes.  When using named pipes, the SQL Server machines have to be in a trust relationship (i.e. same domain), just like a file share.  Named pipes are a similar technology.

Comment: soryy for my delayed response... yes am getting a different error now... `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such host is known`

Comment: And *once again* did you try the ***IP ADDRESS*** instead of the server name? Are you sure you can even ping the ***IP ADDRESS*** from this machine?

Comment: ya i did tried the IP address too... am able to ping the IP from remote machine

Comment: If you can ping the IP address then the error "No such host is known" does not make sense.

Comment: Ohh!!! I pinged the wrong IP. Its getting Request timed out on pinging. Can you guide on the next course of actions

Comment: That would be for your network person. I can't even start to guess at a list of possible reasons you can't ping the server.

Comment: Is it a possibility that the remote computer doesnot allow remote connections?? If so how can I check it??

Comment: Well you're going to need to be able to connect to that server somehow first in order to check any of its configuration options.

Comment: I can connect to the server.. I am having administrator access

Comment: So you can't connect from a 3rd machine? Definitely sounds like a firewall or other routing issue. Are all of these machines in the same domain, different domains, no domain? Where is your workstation, where is the server you're trying to connect to, and where is the machine that won't connect?

Comment: Well I  am on my laptop and i am trying to ping this database server. Regarding domains i have little idea. I am on my laptop and using Remote Desktop Connection to connect to this server.

Comment: It seems to me like you need much more basic help than what this site is intended to provide. Maybe you should pursue your issue over at http://superuser.com/

Comment: Also I have switched off Firewall on both the machines temporarily to check ping. Still its showing Request Timed Out.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron ... will post back if I find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Aaron's suggestion to ensure your connection string uses tcp, run SQL Server Configuration manager and check the following:

- do you have more than one instance?
- tcp/ip enabled?
- if the instance you are targeting is not the default instance, it will not be on port 1433 but rather some dynamic port. The Microsoft libraries figure out which port using [SQL Server Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on port 1434. Your firewall needs to allow that also (UDP).
- if your Express instance is the only instance, you can change to use port 1433. Then you don't need SQL Server Browser.

Comment: Since `InstanceName` returned `NULL`, in spite of the fact that it is SQL Express (and almost always named `SQLEXPRESS`), it seems this is the default instance.